# How to use octokit (github API) in node js application

Tags: node.js, github-api, octokit

I am trying to use github api to create a repository. I have used octokit as specified in the Github API documentation. This is the code which iam using,

```
const Octokit = require("octokit");

async function fileFetch() {
try {
return await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) =\> {
try {
const octokit = new Octokit({
auth: "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",
});
const response = await octokit.request(
`GET /repos/HexaInnovLab/Rapidx_Documentation/contents/website/docusaurus.config.js?ref=master`
);
resolve("success");
console.log(response);
} catch (error) {
reject("error");
console.log(error);
}
});
} catch (error) {
console.log(error);
}
}

fileFetch();
```

But i am getting this error.

```
TypeError: Octokit is not a constructor
at C:\\Users\\55393\\ReactWorkspace\\email-service\\unzip.js:81:25
at new Promise (\<anonymous\>)
at fileFetch (C:\\Users\\55393\\ReactWorkspace\\email-service\\unzip.js:79:18)
at Object.\<anonymous\> (C:\\Users\\55393\\ReactWorkspace\\email-service\\unzip.js:99:1)
at Module.\_compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
at Object.Module.\_extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
at Function.Module.\_load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint \[as runMain\] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
error
```

How to solve this?

I explored for solutions but couldnt find any.

Comment: Use `const {Octokit} = require("octokit")`, because the required package contains an object with members `{Octokit, App}`.

Comment: You saved a lot of time. Thank you so much